# Trying to create a specific loop in excel to get an output

Tags: excel, vba, loops

bear with me on this question. I'm pretty sure it'll be easy for those who have knowledge in this field, but I do not know much about VBA or how to create loops in Excel to be creating this formula:

Please review the picture here

[image]

What I'm trying to construct is a loop that'll concatenate those numbers.
EX. I want to concatenate in this order A2,"-",B2; A3,"-",B2; A4,"-",B2.....A16,"-",B2
Once everything in A1- A16 is concatenated with B2, I want to move on to concatenating A1-A16 with B3.EX: A2,"-",B3; A3,"-",B3.....A16,"-",B3

I know this is possible because certain loops can be created to go through with this procedure, but I do not know VBA and am not sure if this is possible with just the pre-existing formulas in Excel. Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please review the About and How to Ask a good question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, it's pretty simple nested loop. Below code will concatenate the way you wanted and store it to column C.

```
Sub MyConcat()
    Const lColA As Long = 1
    Const lColB As Long = 2
    Const lColTxt As Long = 3 ' concatenated result in Column C
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, sTxt As String
    Dim lRowA As Long, lRowB As Long, lRowTxt As Long

    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to match yours
    lRowA = 1
    lRowTxt = 1
    oWS.Columns(lColTxt).Clear ' remove previous data on Column C
    Do Until IsEmpty(oWS.Cells(lRowA, lColA))
        sTxt = ""
        lRowB = 2
        Do Until IsEmpty(oWS.Cells(lRowB, lColB))
            sTxt = oWS.Cells(lRowA, lColA).Text & "-" & oWS.Cells(lRowB, lColB).Text
            oWS.Cells(lRowTxt, lColTxt) = sTxt
            lRowB = lRowB + 1
            lRowTxt = lRowTxt + 1
        Loop
        lRowA = lRowA + 1
    Loop
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT: This should fit in many situations of number of Parent SKUs.
Usable on your data in second image, including another set of "TuTi" and Parent SKUs of different length. Please try understand it, it will be a whole page of explanations.

```
Private Const lColA As Long = 1
Private Const lColB As Long = 2
Private Const lColTxt As Long = 3 ' concatenated result in Column C

Dim oWS As Worksheet, sGroup As String, lRowCurr As Long, lRowTxt As Long

Sub MyConcat()
    Dim oRng As Range, lStopRow As Long

    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to match yours
    lRowCurr = 1 ' Current Row index
    lRowTxt = 1 ' Results from Row 1
    sGroup = ""
    With oWS
        .Columns(lColTxt).Clear ' remove previous data on Column C
        ' Row of LastCell in current sheet + 1
        lStopRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
        ' Row of "Ctrl-Up" from LastCell Row at column A
        lStopRow = .Cells(lStopRow, lColA).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ' Start processing rows until until StopRow in column A
        Do Until lRowCurr = lStopRow
            Set oRng = .Cells(lRowCurr, lColA)
            If IsGroupCell(oRng) Then
                sGroup = oRng.Value ' Stores Group text
            ElseIf IsParentSKU(oRng) Then
                Call MyConcat2 ' Invoke the mix sub that writes the result in column C
            End If
            lRowCurr = lRowCurr + 1
            Set oRng = Nothing
        Loop
    End With
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub MyConcat2()
    Dim sTxt As String, oRng As Range
    Dim lRowA As Long, lRowB As Long

    lRowA = lRowCurr + 1
    Set oRng = oWS.Cells(lRowA, lColA)
    ' Stop mixing the values when it is a Group or Parent SKU row
    Do Until IsGroupCell(oRng) Or IsParentSKU(oRng) Or IsEmpty(oRng)
        sTxt = ""
        lRowB = lRowCurr + 1
        ' Don't mix if it is a Parent SKU
        Do Until IsParentSKU(oWS.Cells(lRowB, lColA)) Or IsEmpty(oWS.Cells(lRowB, lColB))
            sTxt = oWS.Cells(lRowA, lColA).Text & "-" & oWS.Cells(lRowB, lColB).Text
            oWS.Cells(lRowTxt, lColTxt) = sGroup & "-" & sTxt
            lRowB = lRowB + 1
            lRowTxt = lRowTxt + 1
        Loop
        lRowA = lRowA + 1
        Set oRng = oWS.Cells(lRowA, lColA)
    Loop
    lRowCurr = lRowA - 1
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function IsGroupCell(oRng As Range) As Boolean
    IsGroupCell = (Not IsNumeric(Left(oRng.Value, 1)) And IsEmpty(oRng.Offset(0, 1)))
End Function

Private Function IsParentSKU(oRng As Range) As Boolean
    IsParentSKU = (IsNumeric(oRng.Value) And IsNumeric(oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted. If you have time, can you elaborate to me how it works?

Comment: Okay, so your code works perfectly in the instance that I'm only trying to combine one set of numbers together. What if i wanted more than one set? for example, http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/2950/iypz.jpg, that image shows two sets and it is divided by a "parent sku" which has no dash( that can be the indication) Can you revise the code so that it dose what it does now, but each set of numbers is divided by a parent sku which can be indicated by a number that's lacking "-"

Comment: Thank you very much. the second code worked exactly how I wanted. life, time saver! thank you!